# Different visualisation of color between iPhone and Windows 10 (laptop)

Tags: lightroom, icc-profile

I've just started editing pictures on my Windows 10 Laptop (Asus) with Lightroom. Unfortunately when I upload the picture to my iPhone 8 the colors look different. It's such a pity because the overall result is different.

I started investigated and I realized that it might be related to the color profiles (?), but I haven't obtained any result really.

So I'm asking you guys, How can I make the colors on my screen on Windows 10 looks the same as the colors on my iPhone 8?

EDIT
I might be not clear, I would like to see a picture the same on my laptop and on my iPhone, in particual I would like the laptop to match the iPhone color (so I have to change some setting in the laptop not in the phone).

The other similar question says that one's a to change the monitor calibration, but I have already gone through that and there are still differences between my pc screen and and Iphone.

Comment: Surely you want to see the correct colours on your screen? Rather than get the laptop to match the iphone.

Comment: Re. @SaaruLindestøkke with changing the colour profile of the iPhone - I don't believe you can, and furthermore since the 7 (iirc) Apple have introduced an iOS + hardware feature which "corrects" the colour under different external lighting on the fly.  That said, the iPhone should have pretty accurate colour reproduction - I expect it's the (arguably "cheaper") Asus which will be "more wrong".  The linked question has a good answer - although I doubt you'll get "enough" depth/precision out of a cheaper laptop display to match them perfectly.

Comment: You can calibrate an iPhone screen with X-Rite hard/software, but you then need to view the images on their app. It does work very well.

Comment: Bear in mind that most phones crank up the saturation on their displays; this results in pictures generally looking more pleasing, but they are less accurate. You can calibrate your laptop to match (to a degree - the color gamut of your laptop may fall short of your phone's particularly if your phone uses an OLED screen,) but just keep in mind that you're basically making the screen less accurate.